# React is not loading bootstrap css file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, electron

Here my component

```
import React from 'react'; 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
class Test extends React.Component{
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <button className="btn btn-danger"> Button </button>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
export default Test;
```

the button still a normal html button! this confuse me even in cmd there's no errors.
I'm using react inside an **ElectronJs** app.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: No errors my friend!

Answer (score 5):

Put it in the index.js file where your ReactDOM.render() exists,

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

It will be globally available to all of its child components rendering it.

Comment: It's the same thing, this really confuses me

Comment: you are trying to put it in the child component, it would work, try that once

Comment: try put the complete path of bootstrap folder, node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css, and are you using webpack? if so add css processor to process the css.

Answer (score 1):

On your line 2, add `./`, which should be:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import './bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

---

**Edited:**

In your webpack config file, check the `resolve section`, make sure your bootstrap css file path is included.

Eg:

```
const bootstrapPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
);
```

Which should be something like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        bootstrapPath: path.join(__dirname, 'your complete path')
    },
    root: srcPath,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', srcPath, commonStylePath, bootstrapPath]
}
```

But ensure you have `style loader` and `css loader`. E.g. `loaders:[{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }]`, if not you will have to run `npm install css-loader style-loader --save`

After which you can then use it in the `js` file `require('bootstrap.min.css')`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm importing bootsrap css file from node_modules not from the same folder

Comment: do you have a webpack config file?

Answer (score 1):

If you write your own css, then import it, does it work? If it doesn't, most probably the issue is that you haven't set your webpack to use a CSS loader.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the CSS just for your particular project, you can access it (by putting the following in index.js):

`import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

since `node_modules` folder is a peer of the `src` folder and index.js is inside the `src` folder.